# iptables ban ip

Tags: iptables

I use below command to ban IPs which is hurting my site,but doesn't work. I don't know why

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 89.200.143.50 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s 37.46.112.102 -j DROP
```

Please help

```
Centos 5.7+LAMP

#iptables -L -n output:~

Chain INPUT <policy Accept> 
target INPUT opt source         destination 
DROP   all   --  89.200.143.50  0.0.0.0/0 
DROP   all   --  37.46.112.102  0.0.0.0/0 

Chain FORWARD <policy ACCEPT> 
target prot opt  source       destination

chain OUTPUT <policy Accept> 
target prot opt source        destination
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables -L -n`?

Comment: @Khaled Post the output already.Please help to check

Answer (score 5):

Your rules look OK to me. Two questions I want to ask:

1. How did you know this did not work?
2. Are you filtering the traffic destined to this machine or forwarded to another machine? In the later case, you need to add your rules to `FORWARD` chain.

**Here are some hints to help you:**

To help you debug this, you can use `tcpdump` to check whether your server is responding to traffic coming from these IPs.

Also, you can use `-j LOG` target of `iptables` to make sure these rules are hit. Also, you can view iptables counters by  `iptables -L -n -v`.

Comment: +1... use `-L -n -v`. Seeing counters and the like helps.